# Layout não está se adaptando (XML)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Olá estou com dificuldade em um layout que estou fazendo no Android Studio, no meu celular ele fica perfeito, mas quando passo ele para meu amigo com um celular com a resolução bem menor, o EditText **Mensagem** simplesmente some para ele.

Aqui no meu celular
[image: Aqui Como Fica no Meu celular]

Aqui do do meu amigo

[image: aqui Como fica no celular do meu amigo]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.example.xairo.ces.NovaOuvidoria">




<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
   android:id="@+id/TxtSetor"
   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
   android:textColor="#2c3e50"
   android:textSize="25sp"
   android:textStyle="bold" />



<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/BtnFoto"
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:background="@drawable/camera"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:layout_above="@+id/BtnEnviarOuvidoria"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BtnEnviarOuvidoria" />
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/BtnDocumento"
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:background="@drawable/documento_icon"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BtnVideo"
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/BtnEnviarOuvidoria" />

<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/BtnVideo"
   android:layout_width="80dp"
   android:layout_height="80dp"
   android:background="@drawable/video"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/TxtMensagem"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
   android:background="#033f88"
   android:text="Enviar"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
   android:textSize="18sp"
   android:id="@+id/BtnEnviarOuvidoria"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
   android:background="@drawable/edittext_borda"
   android:id="@+id/TxtMensagem"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ellipsize="start"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:hint="Mensagem"
   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
   android:singleLine="false"
   android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
   android:maxLength="2000"
   android:maxLines="10"
   android:layout_above="@+id/BtnFoto"
   android:layout_below="@+id/lista" />

<Spinner
   android:background="@drawable/edittext_borda"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/lista"
   android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
   android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Comment: Jairo, acho que precisa dar uma olhada na [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html). Nesse caso precisará colocar um nesse layout e definir um tamanho mínimo para seu `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque um ScrollView no seu layout.
Ex:

```
blá blá blá...

< /LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Me parece que seu exemplo ficou incompleto.